# Нахождение числа в таблице

Tags: html, javascript

Как в HTML таблице найти заданное число? Исходный код:

> `<table border="1">`
> `<tbody>`
> `<tr><td>50</td><td>17</td></tr>`
> `<tr><td>14</td><td>90</td></tr>`
> `</tbody>`
> `</table>`
> `<p><b>54 - </b>Нет</p>`
> `<p><b>18 - </b>Нет</p>`
> `<p><b>14 - </b>Есть!</p>`

Итог:

> <table border="1"><tbody>
> <tr><td>50</td><td>17</td></tr>
> <tr><td>14</td><td>90</td></tr></tbody></table><br>
> <p><b>54 - </b>Нет</p>
> <p><b>18 - </b>Нет</p>
> <p><b>14 - </b>Есть!</p>

Как сделать так, чтобы Javascript определял, есть ли в таблице числа '54', '18' и '14', которые приведены под таблицей. Только вместо них будут стоять числа от 1 до 90. Результат, должен быть записан в месте, где написано "Есть!" и "Нет", то есть присутствуют они или нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Тестируем в песочнице](http://jsfiddle.net/nhbv4wvp/)

```
var d = document,
    nums = [54, 18, 14],
    tmp = d.createDocumentFragment(),
    vals = [].map.call(d.querySelectorAll('table td'), function (td) {
        return +td.textContent;
    });
for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    var p = d.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = '<b>' + nums[i] + ' - </b>' + (vals.indexOf(nums[i]) != -1 ? 'Есть' : 'Нет');
    tmp.appendChild(p);
}
d.body.appendChild(tmp);
```

Comment: А ещё вопросик: если я создам две такие таблицы, то можно, чтобы он искал эти числа сначала в одной таблице и записывал результат, а затем в другой таблице искал и результат записывал под ней?..

Comment: @Никита___, можно. [Смотрите пример][1].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/nhbv4wvp/3/

Comment: А как вместо "d.createElement('p')..." сделать код: если число есть в таблице, то пусть оно станет красным цветом в таблице? Что-то типа того...

Comment: Это, наверное, как-то так: 

document.nums.setAttribute('color','rgb(255, 0, 0)')

Comment: @Никита___, вот [так можно][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/nhbv4wvp/4/